# Splitting line on python

Tags: python, split, filenames

I need to use a python code without editing it (another's code).
At some point, this code reads the line of a text file to get some file names.
To do so, it uses a  `line.split()`

On the example I was given, I had a file name like `/home/directory/fileName`

When I do a split on such a line, I get `['/home/directory/fileName\]`

The point is the files I work on are located on "My Passport".

I had errors during the execution of the code that are caused by the name of the file.
Indeed, when I tried on python to split the following line: `/media/My Passport/directory/fileName`, I have `['`/media/My', 'Passport/directory/fileName`']`, so a list with two elements, which the program I have cannot handle. This is because at some point of this code, fileName[0][0] is called, which should be `['`/media/My 'Passport/directory/fileName`']`, but which is `['`/media/My', 'Passport/directory/fileName`']`

I tried to change the name of my device, but it [turns out](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1418861) I need to reformat it to do so... which I can't...

Anyone has an idea how I can handle this problem, specifically how I can modify the file names so that, after a line.split(), I get `['`/media/My 'Passport/directory/fileName`']` ??

Thank you

**EDIT**

I have a text file in which I have a list of file names with their path

> /media/My Passport/fileName1
>
> /media/My Passport/fileName2
>
> /media/My Passport/fileName3

I have a code where I split the lines of this file line.split() to get lists like

> ['/media/My Passport/fileName1']

I know I can get such lists using line.split(\n), but I have to use line.split()

I am looking for a way to modify the text file so that, when I run line.split(), I get lists like

> ['/media/My Passport/fileName1']

and not

> ['/media/My',  'Passport/fileName1']

I have been trying to change the file text using brackets and backslashes :

"/media/My Passport/fileName1"
/media/My\ Passport/fileName1

but the same problem remains

Comment: CRYSTAL BALL BROKEN. SHOW US WHAT YOU ARE DOING.

Comment: Is there more than one file name per line? Why do you need to split?

Comment: string.split() will split on spaces without arguments, maybe you want os.path.split? Still not sure what you're doing post and example please

Comment: You HAVE to use the wrong thing? You HAVE to?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say you have

```
splitted_result = ['/media/My', 'Passport/fileName1']
```

Then you can do a simple join

```
>>> [' '.join(splitted_result)]
['/media/My Passport/fileName1']
```

This will output a list as its result.